# case statement - help required

Tags: sql, case

I am new to write queries , i have a table here and wanted to write a query for that

[image]

```
No:     Desc                                 Name
1         apple                              fruit
2         apple raw                          fruit
3         apple ripe                         fruit
4         APPLE                              fruit
5         tomato                             veg
6         tomato 2                           veg
```

so here i am looking for a `case` statement , whatever the `description(Desc)` is it should be categorised as above (`Name`)

NOTE : sometimes Apple can be all upper case , all lower case , numerical value also added along with name
how do i write a case statement for that
looking forward for response

looking for case statement

Comment: `CASE` is an expression, not a statement.

Comment: Hi - please update your question with your attempt to write the relevant SQL statement and ask a specific question about whatever you then have an issue with

Comment: Dai, you have to show result that you want. Or in other case you have to explain your problem very weel.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a `case expression` to achieve your request - you MIGHT need a `column alias` like this:

```
SELECT No, Name AS Description
FROM YOURTABLE
```

OR: if you are asking for a `concatenation` of Name and Description then the solution can differ depending on which database you use: e.g.

```
SELECT NO, Name|| ' ' || Desc AS Description
FROM YOURTABLE
```

IF using `||` won't work in your database then instead use `+` if using MS SQL Server or perhaps try:

```
SELECT No, CONCAT(Name,' ',Desc) AS Description
FROM YOURTABLE
```

For reference a `case expression` isn't difficult e.g.

```
SELECT No
    , CASE WHEN Desc LIKE '% %' THEN Name ELSE Desc END AS name2
FROM YOURTABLE
```

You only need a `case expression` if you need to do different things depending on some value(s) in the row.